# Rails app on heroku: blank pages on a specific computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a fairly vanilla Rails application on heroku that works fine ... except on my Dad's computer. It is Windows 7, and the site always shows as a blank page. I have checked the following:

- Both Chrome, Firefox and IE (latest versions) all exhibit the problem. Web inspector on Chrome and FF shows either a 200 or 304 response code, but blank body.
- I have tried clearing the cache.
- Curl on his machine successfully downloads the page.
- My laptop on his network views the page fine.
- His laptop on other networks still exhibits the problem.
- His other laptop works fine.
- Multiple other machines (5+) work fine.
- Server logs show a successful response being served.
- Turned off Microsoft Security Essentials.
- Turned off the firewall.

I'm stumped. **What other debugging steps should I try?**

For reference, the site is http://gccc.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Chrome has a known bug where a page loads but it is displayed as a blank page. For some solutions, see here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340138 As for the other browsers, I don't know.

Comment: Ah I hadn't checked for anti-virus or anything like that, thanks for the tip. Will report back.

Comment: the above wasn't it, updated post.

Comment: Have you checked for a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: "His other laptop works fine." What OS/version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from twitter: https://www.malwarebytes.org/ picked up a couple of Trojans that were causing issues. I had assumed "Microsoft Security Essentials" was doing this, but I guess that is something different.